# How to move hamburger menu icon to the right side?

Tags: hamburger-menu

I want to move my hamburger menu icon, on mobile, to the right side of the screen. Currently it resides on the left. However, any attempt to do so with relative/absolute positioning moves the site title out of view (and makes the nav bar buggy). I can’t find a way to make things play nicely. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

My site: www.tylercharboneauprofessional.com

Answer (score 0):

remove `left: .5em;` and add `right:0;`

**Fix css below:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
  .banner-content-page-title-description #mobile-navigation-label,
  .banner-content-empty #mobile-navigation-label {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75em;
    /* left: .5em; */
    right: 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Vincent1989 - Thanks for the code. Unfortunately, the menu icon just moves to the center of the navigation bar (not the right), and the site title disappears completely. Any ideas?